# Why am I getting xhr failed for post in "file.php" i?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send simple form to the server using ajax. However, on accessing some fields, the console gives me XHR failed for post. My ajax code is as follows; it works:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
            $("#profile-form").submit(function(event){

                var data = $(this).serialize();

                $.ajax({    
                    type    : "POST",
                    url     : "profile.php",
                    data    : data,
                    success : function(response){

                        alert(response);
                        location.reload();

                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

I am simply trying to get the contents of the form data using $_POST in my PHP page. However, it gives me XHR failed loading for some entries of the form. Any idea why?

Comment: did you try to add event.preventDefault();  in beginning of click event??

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef I tried doing that however the application failed. I tried following..

Comment: $(document)
  .on('click', 'form button[type=submit]', function(e) {
      var isValid = $(e.target).parents('form').isValid();

      console.log("Submit clicked..");

      if(!isValid) {
        e.preventDefault(); //prevent the default action
      } else{
       var data = $(this).serialize();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

    $.ajax({

     type    : "POST",
     url     : "profile.php",
     data    : data,
     success : function(response){
      
      alert(response);
      location.reload();

     }
    });
      }
  });

Comment: try to put something else in data instead of serialize....also is profile.php accessible from where you are ??

Comment: @HalayemAnis I want to pass form-data thats why I took it. If I pass anything else. I am able to access it in my profile.php. Yes my profile.php is in the same directory

Comment: can you execute this code and send back the result : `$( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log( $( this ).serialize() );
});`

Comment: @HalayemAnis it doesnt print anything in the log.

Comment: edit your question by adding your html form